# Is it a security risk if the /tmp folder is not owned by root?

Tags: security

Is it a possible hole of security having /tmp/ folder under user owner instead of root?

I have set it temporally under my user by mistake, after that its impossible to bring it back to root user: Ubuntu after that doesent recognize my session.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there's an inherent risk if /tmp doesn't belong to root, but it should belong to root following best practices (it's a system directory).

Also, note that the /tmp directory permissions must have the sticky bit set:

```
drwxrwxrwt  4 root root  4096 2012-02-19 19:56 tmp
```

This way, files created in /tmp can be read and written only by the user that creates them. Not doing this is indeed a security risk as users could write or delete files that belong to other users or processes.

Regarding your session, I believe you should be able to solve this by changing the ownership from a console, while the X system is down (go to a TTY console with CTRL+ALT+F1, `service lightdm stop` (or `service gdm stop`), change ownership and reboot).

To change owner and permissions, you can use:

```
sudo chown root:root /tmp
sudo chmod 1777 /tmp
```

Comment: my folder tmp/ is actually : drwxrwxr-x  13 papachan root     4096 2012-02-19 14:23 tmp
actually iam able to resolve the session problem by starting Reconvery console and change my user PASSWD

Comment: maybe the problem session is another problem... now my /tmp folder belong to root user and with the correct permissions as you mentioned. and i can login to my session

Comment: I updated my answer with the commands you can use to fix this. Make sure you reboot after the changes: in this case you want to be sure that everything remains correct after rebooting.

Comment: His session problem was the strange permissions on /tmp that caused explosion after changing owner back to root.